# Convert Set to cats.data.NonEmptySet?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Is there an extension method in cats for the standard `Set` which converts it to `Option[cats.data.NonEmptySet]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not for `scala.collection.immutable.Set`, but for `SortedSet`:

```
scala> import cats.syntax.set._
import cats.syntax.set._

scala> import scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet
import scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet

scala> SortedSet(1, 2, 3).toNes
res0: Option[cats.data.NonEmptySet[Int]] = Some(TreeSet(1, 2, 3))
```

You can of course convert an ordinary `Set`:

```
scala> Set(1, 2, 3).to[SortedSet].toNes
res1: Option[cats.data.NonEmptySet[Int]] = Some(TreeSet(1, 2, 3))
```

Cats's `NonEmptySet` isn't built on `Set` (and Cats doesn't provide syntax for `Set`) because `Set` relies on universal equality to determine what counts as uniqueness for its elements. `SortedSet` on the other hand requires a `scala.math.Ordering` instance, which makes it more aligned with the design principles followed in Cats (see e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/123) for more discussion).

Comment: Seems like another import is needed for the `.to[SortedSet]` call.